# Accidental override by migrate to androidx

Tags: generics, kotlin

kotlin: 1.2.71
andorid studio: 3.2.1
gradle plugin: 3.2.0
gradle: 4.6

---

I`m getting an "accidental override" error(code sample from below), if u find any wrong use, please tell me, be appreciated.

```
abstract class ResourceLiveData<T: Resource<*>> : LiveData<T>(){

    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
        do something here ...
        super.observe(owner, observer)
    }
}
```

demo impl code:

```
// Inherited platform declarations clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (observe(Landroidx/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner;Landroidx/lifecycle/Observer;)V):
//   fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<Resource<String>>): Unit defined in  com.demo.live.StringResourceLiveData 
//   fun observe(p0: LifecycleOwner, p1: Observer<in Resource<String>!>): Unit defined in com.demo.live.StringResourceLiveData 

class StringResourceLiveData : ResourceLiveData<Resource<String>>()
```

#### UPDATE

The `ResourceLiveData` is in the third-party-lib, and the lib dependence `android.arch.lifecycle`.

My App is migrating to androidx, so, i add `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` in gradle.properties.

After sync, `ResourceLiveData.class` import have change to androidx, but problem here, `ResourceLiveData` override method not contain contravariant `in`, but `androidx.lifecycle.LiveData` need it

Comment: Please post the full error you're getting.

Comment: @EvanKnowles This is a compilation error, full message has been posted in the sample code comments

Answer (score 5):

Your code has a bunch of issues.

- `ResourceLiveData` needs to be `open` if you want to extend it.
- The override is defined incorrectly. I used the IDE to generate the correct version
- Extending from a class requires you to call the super class constructor `()`

Here's the corrected code

```
open class ResourceLiveData<T: Resource<*>> : LiveData<T>(){
    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
        do something here ...
        super.observe(owner, observer)
    }
}

class StringResourceLiveData : ResourceLiveData<Resource<String>>()
```

Comment: My mistake, `ResourceLiveData` in this example is the abstract class